# Retrieve sum of filtered records from core data and display results to a label

Tags: ios, core-data

I want to query my entity "DIncome" to sum the attribute "credit" But I only want entires that have their "daystamp" attribute equal to today. The following code gets me close but I don't understand how to finish this code in order to output the sum of credit DIncome attribute to a label on my view controller.

Heres what I got;

```
//Get today date
NSDate *dateSelect = [NSDate date];

//formate today date as day only "dd"
NSDateFormatter *dfdd = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dfdd setDateFormat:@"dd"];
NSString *formattedDatedd = [dfdd stringFromDate:dateSelect];

//Fetchrequest
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"DIncome" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[request setEntity:entity];

// Specify that the request should return dictionaries.
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

// Create an expression for the key path.
NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"credit"];

NSExpression *sumExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"sum:" arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:keyPathExpression]];

// Create an expression description using the minExpression and returning a date.
NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];

// The name is the key that will be used in the dictionary for the return value.
[expressionDescription setName:@"sumCredit"];
[expressionDescription setExpression:sumExpression];
[expressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSDateAttributeType];

// Set the request's properties to fetch just the property represented by the expressions.
[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:expressionDescription]];

// Execute the fetch.
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (objects == nil) {
    // Handle the error.
}
else {
    if ([objects count] > 0) {
        NSLog(@"Credit Sum: %@", [[objects objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"sumCredit"]);
        self.dayDisplayLabel.text = sumExpression;
    }
}
```

For the second part of the question I need to set the sum of the credit to my dayDisplayLabel
This is not working because its an incompatible pointer assigning NSString to NSExpression

```
self.dayDisplayLabel.text = sumExpression;
```

How do I make this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to filter your query results you need to setPredicate for your request like so

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"daystamp = %@", formattedDatedd];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
```

And to display this to your label, use the same line you are using in the NSLog line.

```
[[objects objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"sumCredit"]
```

if would look like this,

```
self.dayDisplayLabel.text = [[objects objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"sumCredit"];
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType]` with `propertiesToFetch` to retrieve only certain attributes of your managed objects. If you want to limit the recorded records, you can use NSPredicate (acts like the WHERE clause in a SQL statement).

Comment: Ok, I have the NSPredicate working. When I NSLog(@"%@", predicate); The output looks like this (daystamp ==16) Which is correct because today is the 16th. But I cant figure out how to set my display labels text to the output of the predicate. The display label should read 16.

Comment: I'm not sure we're on the same boat. What exactly are you trying to do? `NSPredicate` acts like the WHERE clause in a SQL statement. It sounds as though you're just looking for the current date, which you could get using `[NSDate date]`. To get the value of the day of the month, you could use the `NSDateFormatter` instance method `stringFromDate:` with the date format set to `@"dd"`.

Comment: I'm using NSDate in the "WHERE" clause to filter the results returned from the database. I only want to see entries for today. I want to pull all the records for today. So I'm using predicate like this; NSPredicate *predicateDay = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"daystamp = %@", formattedDatedd]; Next I would like to get the dollar amount assosiated with these entries for this particular day and add them up so I can show the user "You have made $450 today!" The $450 would be the sum of all the records with a "daystamp == today's date."

Comment: Looks like you're looking for https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002484-SW6. You'll have to use `expressionForFunction:@"sum:" arguments:@[[NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"YourIncomeAttributeName"]]` method.

Comment: OK, I have this working sort of... I dont understand now how to incorporate the predicate so I can filter the @"credit" attribute. I want to sum and output to a label all the "credit" income for today only. In the old predicate statement I had "NSPredicate *predicateDay = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"daystamp = %@", formattedDatedd];" I'm having trouble figuring out how to use the predicate statement to filter by the daystamp attribute for a given record

Comment: I updated my question to focus more on exactly what I'm trying to accomplish. I posted the actual code I'm using which I got from the link you provided, I changed as much I could to make it work for me but I have reached my understandings of objective C at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch requests return their results as arrays of managed objects. You can get attribute values from those objects. In your case you get an array of managed objects representing the `DIncome` entity type. If you subclassed `NSManagedObject` then these are instances of your subclass; if you didn't subclass then they're instances of `NSManagedObject`.

To get values of string attributes from these instances, use key-value coding. If your attribute were named "title", you'd get the string value of the first object with:

```
NSString *firstTitle = [mutableFetchResults[0] valueForKey:@"title"];
```

Get the values of any other attributes using similar code.

If you want the fetch request to only include a subset of the instances of `DIncome`, look into `NSPredicate`. You can use this like a SQL "WHERE" clause to request only instances matching specific criteria, e.g.:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@", someNameString];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
```